# ¿Formula para detectar la formulacion porcentual exacta que representa un numero entre un total determinado?

Tags: javascript

Necesito  encontrar la formula matematica para hallar un numero porcentual dado, en el siguiente dejo el codigo que corre los numeros de 1 al 1000 y determina la cantidad de numeros creciente, decreciente y mixtos ejemplo 146 es creciente, 952 es decreciente y 592 es mixto, la cuestion esta en que los resultados del programa me arroja los siguientes resultados:

```
1000 números
156 son crecientes (15.6%) (Numeros Acumulados que son Creciente)
220 son decrecientes (22%) (Numeros Acumulados que son Decreciente)
525 son Mixtos (52.5%)     (Numeros Acumulados que son Mixtos)
```

EJEMPLO 2: el codigo expresado me refleja el que el numero 538 es justamente numero que representa el 50% del total de los numeros

LA PREGUNTA ES HALLAR UNA FORMULA PARA QUE SEGUN EL PORCENTAJE ME ARROJE EL NUMERO EXACTO COMO SE MUESTRA EN EL EJEMPLO 2.

*************** Espero me puedan ayudar solo me falta esto para terminar**************

```
function DeterminaNumero(numero){
        var num = numero.toString()
        var a = num.split(''); // separa los digitos y los convierte en matriz
        if (a.length == 3) {
            if (a[0] >= a[1] && a[1] >= a[2]) {      
                decrecientes++;             
                return "decreciente: " /*+ decrecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%"*/;
            } else {
                if (a[0] <= a[1] && a[1] <= a[2]) {
                    crecientes++;
                    return "creciente: "/*+ crecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%"*/;
                } else {
                    mixtos++;
                    return "mixto: "+ mixtos*100/totalNumeros +"%";
                }
            }
        }
}

var crecientes=0;
        var decrecientes=0;
        var mixtos=0;
        var totalNumeros=0;

        var optimo=0;
        var min=0;


        for(var i=1;i<=1600000;i++){
            totalNumeros++;
            var resultado = DeterminaNumero(i);
            document.write(i +" es " + resultado +"<br>");
        }

        document.write("------------------------ Resultados ----------------------------<br>");
        document.write(totalNumeros + " números<br>");
        document.write(crecientes + " son crecientes ("+ crecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%)<br>");
        document.write(decrecientes + " son decrecientes ("+ decrecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%)<br>");
        document.write(mixtos + " son Bouncy ("+ mixtos*100/totalNumeros +"%)<br>");
        document.write("------------------------ Numero Minimo ----------------------------<br>");

     //document.write("El Numero minimo para una proporcion Mixta es de 50% es:538 ");
     document.write("Numero Mixto 50% es: "+ min);
```

Comment: Por favor, redacta mejor tus preguntas. Es la segunda que haces sobre este ejercicio y se sigue sin entender bien

Answer (score 0):

Buenos dias si le ruego disculpas de verdad si redacte mal la pregunta he aqui lo que quiero:
De este codigo
 mixtos++;

if (mixtos*100/totalNumeros==50) {
                    min=(50*totalNumeros)/100;
                    optimo=min
                }

quiero saber la formula que me de exactamente con el numero que representa 50%, cuando corro el programa este numero es 538, pero no hallo la manera de que se visualise automaticamente, lo que quiero es una formula que me lo encuentre, almacenarlo en una variable para despues mostarlo como un rsultado.

```
function DeterminaNumero(numero){
        var num = numero.toString()
        var a = num.split(''); // separa los digitos y los convierte en matriz
        if (a.length == 3) {
            if (a[0] >= a[1] && a[1] >= a[2]) {      
                decrecientes++;             
                return "decreciente: " /*+ decrecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%"*/;
            } else {
                if (a[0] <= a[1] && a[1] <= a[2]) {
                    crecientes++;
                    return "creciente: "/*+ crecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%"*/;
                } else {
                    mixtos++;
                    if (mixtos*100/totalNumeros==50) {
                        min=(50*totalNumeros)/100;
                        optimo=min
                    }
                    return "mixto: "+ mixtos*100/totalNumeros +"% ";
                }
            }
        }
}

var crecientes=0;
        var decrecientes=0;
        var mixtos=0;
        var totalNumeros=0;

        var optimo=0;
        var min=0;


        for(var i=1;i<=1000;i++){
            totalNumeros++;
            var resultado = DeterminaNumero(i);
            document.write(i +" es " + resultado +"<br>");
        }

        document.write("------------------------ Resultados ----------------------------<br>");
        document.write(totalNumeros + " números<br>");
        document.write(crecientes + " son crecientes ("+ crecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%)<br>");
        document.write(decrecientes + " son decrecientes ("+ decrecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%)<br>");
        document.write(mixtos + " son Bouncy ("+ mixtos*100/totalNumeros +"%)<br>");
        document.write("------------------------ Numero Minimo ----------------------------<br>");

     //document.write("El Numero minimo para una proporcion mixto es de 50% es:538 ");
     document.write("Numero Mixto 99% es: "+ min +" "+ optimo);
```